# What is the GUID suffix on key container storage files in Windows?

Tags: windows, security, cryptoapi, cng

I am wondering what are the GUID suffixes for the RSA key container files stored in the machine and user key container stores. I cannot identify some of these as key containers through CAPI/CNG, although I'll expose my case using command line tools instead. Commands below are for PowerShell in an elevated prompt. On most machines, the GUID suffix is the same for all these file names, but on this one there are *four* different GUIDs, while the API is returning only keys with only one. **What is this GUID?** I do not like random secrets stored by I do not know what on my machine; **are they safe to delete?**

The content of the machine store directory is:

```
> ls -n $env:ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\Rsa\MachineKeys  | sort { "$_"[-3..-1] }
d1f9044f5d7345da71c0d2efd2e4f59e_e9f96f2e-b8b7-49b2-85a5-840195eca603
d6d986f09a1ee04e24c949879fdb506c_a4dc5a56-574d-4e4b-ba8d-d88984f9a6c5
6de9cb26d2b98c01ec4e9e8b34824aa2_a4dc5a56-574d-4e4b-ba8d-d88984f9a6c5
76944fb33636aeddb9590521c2e8815a_a4dc5a56-574d-4e4b-ba8d-d88984f9a6c5
d6d986f09a1ee04e24c949879fdb506c_f7fe3b04-ef9b-4b27-827f-953c5743e2ec
d1f9044f5d7345da71c0d2efd2e4f59e_f7fe3b04-ef9b-4b27-827f-953c5743e2ec
76944fb33636aeddb9590521c2e8815a_f7fe3b04-ef9b-4b27-827f-953c5743e2ec
6de9cb26d2b98c01ec4e9e8b34824aa2_f7fe3b04-ef9b-4b27-827f-953c5743e2ec
ba8e1b9b5510957b3af7b811f05660de_f7fe3b04-ef9b-4b27-827f-953c5743e2ec
d1f9044f5d7345da71c0d2efd2e4f59e_c6a7fc9d-32a6-41e4-afd5-7dc7b822029e
```

I sorted the list by the last three characters, so that it's easy to see in a glance that there are 4 distinct GUID suffixes to the key container files. Now let's enumerate the key reported by all installed CSPs. I'll get the list of providers, and later the list of each provider's keys using the `certutil` tool that comes with Windows. Its output requires some regex magic for parsing, which is not essential, just convenient:

```
> certutil -csplist | sls  '^Provider Name: (.*)' | %{ $_.Matches[0].Groups[1].Value }
Microsoft Base Cryptographic Provider v1.0
Microsoft Base DSS and Diffie-Hellman Cryptographic Provider
Microsoft Base DSS Cryptographic Provider
[...snip...]
```

The output for a single key lists the name, flags and the key container ID, the latter matching respective file name in the above directory (of course, we can see more keys from additional KSPs, smart cards, TPM etc.). Example for one provider (the `-q` makes some providers fail silently instead of asking for user's action, such as inserting a SmartCard):

```
> certutil -key -q
Microsoft Strong Cryptographic Provider:
  iisConfigurationKey
  6de9cb26d2b98c01ec4e9e8b34824aa2_f7fe3b04-ef9b-4b27-827f-953c5743e2ec
  RSA
    AT_KEYEXCHANGE

  iisWasKey
  76944fb33636aeddb9590521c2e8815a_f7fe3b04-ef9b-4b27-827f-953c5743e2ec
  [...snip...]
```

Some key names are just GUIDs too, but if we grep out only the lines that start with at the least 20 hex digits, there will be only the IDs listed. So all key IDs from all providers can be concisely shown with:

```
> certutil -csplist | sls '^Provider Name: (.*)' | %{ $_.Matches[0].Groups[1].Value } |
%{ certutil -key -q -csp "$_" } | sls '^\s+[0-9a-f]{20}.+' | sort -u

  597367cc37b886d7ee6c493e3befb421_f7fe3b04-ef9b-4b27-827f-953c5743e2ec
  6de9cb26d2b98c01ec4e9e8b34824aa2_f7fe3b04-ef9b-4b27-827f-953c5743e2ec
  76944fb33636aeddb9590521c2e8815a_f7fe3b04-ef9b-4b27-827f-953c5743e2ec
  ba8e1b9b5510957b3af7b811f05660de_f7fe3b04-ef9b-4b27-827f-953c5743e2ec
  d6d986f09a1ee04e24c949879fdb506c_f7fe3b04-ef9b-4b27-827f-953c5743e2ec
  f0e91f6485ac2d09485e4ec18135601e_f7fe3b04-ef9b-4b27-827f-953c5743e2ec
```

Here are actually 2 more keys than there are in the MachineKeys directory (they come from the KSP, in fact, `certutil -key -csp KSP` shows them, if you are wondering). But the fact is they all have the same GUID suffix `_f7fe3b04-ef9b-4b27-827f-953c5743e2ec`.

The machine was installed by the vendor (an HP notebook, to be exact). This is unlike other machines, that we assemble or buy barebone and install and configure by ourselves. And I am working with some sensitive data sometimes, so I am indeed <s>paranoid</s> vetting the software thoroughly before allowing machines to access sensitive data.

The OS is Windows 10, if that matters, but the same type of storage has not changed from Windows 7, AFAIK, even with the introduction of the new CNG API in 8.0 (or 8.1?).

---

Just in case anyone would find useful a PowerShell snippet to readably list keys by provider, I used this command:

```
> certutil -csplist | sls  '^Provider Name: (.*)' | %{ $_.Matches[0].Groups[1].Value } |
%{ Write-Host -for Yellow "`n$_"; certutil -key -q -csp "$_" }
```

Comment: I am trying to figure this out too. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer here: https://serverfault.com/a/642279/451491

> The file naming convention is x_y, where x is a random GUID to
>   uniquely identify the key, and y is the machine GUID found at
>   HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Cryptography.

Comment: Thanks. Not a complete solution, but still a useful bit of information!